# Create String from double (62^16="ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ")

Tags: java, string, encoding, int

I need to create a `String` (kinda like an encryption) from a `double`, so if it is 16 characters long there are 62^16 (26 capital letters, 26 small letters, 10 numbers, ^16 characters) possibilities. I have no idea how to do that.

So the last one should be "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
and the first one "0000000000000001"
the second one  "0000000000000002"
the 62th one "000000000000000Z"
and the 63th one "0000000000000010".

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: An `int` isn't big enough to support 62^16 different values.

Comment: oh, sorry, in my code I used doubles. that worked fine, but you are right. I'll edit that :)

Comment: A `double` also isn't big enough to support 62^16 different values.

Comment: Thats strange, but it worked o.O I was wondering, why you can use a double, but it worked so far.

Comment: A `double` is 64 bits.  64-bit is enough to represent around 10 characters (assuming 62 unique character values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a BigInteger object, to store your numbers.
The first first one is (0) "0000000000000000" and the last one is (62^16 - 1) "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ".

```
private static final BigInteger BIG_INTEGER_62 = BigInteger.valueOf(62);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(encryptInteger(BigInteger.valueOf(0)));
    System.out.println(encryptInteger(BigInteger.valueOf(1)));
    System.out.println(encryptInteger(BigInteger.valueOf(62)));
    System.out.println(encryptInteger(BigInteger.valueOf(63)));
    System.out.println(encryptInteger(BIG_INTEGER_62.pow(16).subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1))));
}

private static String encryptInteger(BigInteger number) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(16);
    for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        builder.append(intToChar(number.divide(BIG_INTEGER_62.pow(i)).mod(BIG_INTEGER_62).intValue()));
    }
    return builder.reverse().toString();
}

private static char intToChar(int value) {
    if(value < 0)
        return '<';
    if(value < 10)
        return (char) ('0' + value);
    if(value < 36)
        return (char) ('a' - 10 + value);
    if(value < 62)
        return (char) ('A' - 36 + value);
    return '>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I just found a solution myself by just using an array if ints :) yours is probably better than mine :)

Comment: @Addi: Why don't you just use an array of characters, AKA the String you already have?

Comment: And how do you obtain these array of ints? I thought you start with a number and not with an array of numbers ranging vom 0 to 61.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after trying a bit I decided to use an Array of ints instead:

```
`public static String salat(int input[])
{
    String ret ="";
    String[] chars = new String[16];
    char[] dict62="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i< 16; i++)
    {
        chars[i]=String.valueOf(dict62[input[i]]);
        ret=ret+chars[i];
    }
    return ret;
}`
```

so

```
salat(new int[]{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0});
```

will return baaaaaaaaaaaaaaa :) the only problem is the array needed. 
Kind of messy but it works ;)
btw: "salat" is just salad in german :D